# Python Regex: Only Replace captured group

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex that matches an "aliases" key that is an existing list in a markdown file, and captures the closing bracket as a group.

```
RE_ALIASES = re.compile(r'\s*---\n.*aliases:\s?\[.*(\]|\n\]).*\n---.*', re.DOTALL)
```

How do I replace that captured group with my own text?

i.e.,

```
---
...
aliases: [
   hello,
   world
]
---
...
```

should be

```
---
...
aliases: [
   hello,
   world,
   inserted
]
---
...
```

In this case, the first group `\n]` is replaced by `,\n    inserted\n]`

Comment: Use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the [re.sub function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

Here's how it would work for your case:

(Supposing you saved your initial string as initial_string)

```
final_string = re.sub('(\\]|\\n\\]).*', ',\n\tinserted\n\t]', initial_string)
```

If you print "final_string" it shows:

```
---
...
aliases: [
        hello,
        world,
        inserted
        ]
---
...
```